# Read json and create variables 1,2,3

Tags: javascript, php, json

This is my json, i want to read this json with php.

Example:

```
$post['1']="Inter BRUSA shared Jornalistas Livre`s photo."; // json readed
$post['2']="Veja como foi a jornada do Inter BRUSA no ato de ontem! Desde Nova Iguaçu até a Cinelândia! westandwitheducation";
```

...

How to make this?

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "story": "Inter BRUSA shared Jornalistas Livres's photo.",
      "created_time": "2016-03-03T21:00:20+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_950798161676140"
    },
    {
      "message": "Veja como foi a jornada do Inter BRUSA no ato de ontem! Desde Nova Iguaçu até a Cinelândia!
#westandwitheducation",
      "created_time": "2016-03-03T17:03:39+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_950700695019220"
    },
    {
      "story": "Inter BRUSA shared Integral da depressão's photo.",
      "created_time": "2016-03-02T22:17:55+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_950312345058055"
    },
    {
      "message": "\"O que eles roubaram foi bem mais do que dinheiro
Roubaram nosso orgulho de ser brasileiro
Mas isso ainda conservo
Podem acabar com a nossa verba
Mas não podem acabar com nosso verbo\"",
      "created_time": "2016-03-02T19:25:07+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_950232311732725"
    },
    {
      "message": "Live from Rio de Janeiro by Jean Carlos",
      "created_time": "2016-03-02T18:09:09+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_950201221735834"
    },
    {
      "message": "Queridos alunos, assim como foi prometido, os alunos marcaram na estação de Comendador Soares às 13h. 
Esperamos por todos lá!",
      "created_time": "2016-03-02T13:28:41+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_950083411747615"
    },
    {
      "story": "Inter BRUSA updated their cover photo.",
      "created_time": "2016-03-01T01:27:03+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_949274608495162"
    },
    {
      "message": "Professores das escolas da rede estadual vão fazer, nesta quarta-feira, uma paralisação de 24 horas. A categoria também promoverá um ato público nas escadarias da Assembleia Legislativa do Rio (Alerj) às 15h. Na ocasião será ministrada uma aula pública com o objetivo de alertar a população sobre as consequências da crise econômica na educação do Estado do Rio. Segundo o Sindicato Estadual dos Profissionais da Educação (Sepe), alunos e profissionais da área sofrem com cortes causados pela crise econômica desde o ano passado.

Nota: O Inter BRUSA apoia o ato e convoca todos para participar!",
      "created_time": "2016-02-29T20:36:25+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_949182335171056"
    },
    {
      "story": "Inter BRUSA updated their profile picture.",
      "created_time": "2016-02-29T11:18:08+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_948940368528586"
    },
    {
      "story": "Inter BRUSA shared Consulado Geral dos Estados Unidos-RJ's post.",
      "created_time": "2016-02-28T22:31:41+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_948694991886457"
    },
    {
      "message": "Isso mesmo!! Mais de 30 minutos!! Você não vai se arrepender

https://soundcloud.com/interbrusa/podcast-4semana-de-fevereiro",
      "created_time": "2016-02-27T00:42:38+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_947599288662694"
    },
    {
      "story": "Inter BRUSA shared Inglês na Ponta da Língua's post.",
      "created_time": "2016-02-26T13:42:50+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_947314072024549"
    },
    {
      "story": "Inter BRUSA shared Consulado Geral dos Estados Unidos-RJ's post.",
      "created_time": "2016-02-26T11:39:58+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_947270985362191"
    },
    {
      "message": "Vejam o que nossos amigos do Brasil-China estão passando!",
      "story": "Inter BRUSA shared Ensino Médio Intercultural Brasil-China's video.",
      "created_time": "2016-02-26T11:37:05+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_947270065362283"
    },
    {
      "message": "Acabamos de receber um lindo texto sobre profissionais da educação, olhem: 
\"Este é um desabafo anônimo, não por medo ou vergonha, mas porque ele não deve ter um rosto único. Ele é um desabafo de nós, alunos, para vocês professores.
 Se eu tivesse apenas um desejo hoje eu diria o dobro de dinheiro e metade da jornada não, apenas pediria dignidade. Hoje escrevo isso com lágrimas nos olhos. Isso que você vai ler não é nada além de um desabafo.
Eu nem sempre fui exemplar, nem sempre assisti a todas as aulas, nem sempre gostei de todos os professores, mas eu sempre os respeitei. Em duas semanas de aula eu sinto muito mais pelos meus professores do que senti a vida toda. Deixou de ser apenas respeito! Eu os admiro como jamais admirarei alguém. É aterrorizador entrar em uma escola e ver seus professores como zeladores ou porteiros. Não porque sejam profissões de menor dignidade, mas porque se pararmos para pensar, eles tem exercido funções a mais e recebido menos (aqueles que receberam). Existem poucos professores no ambiente escolar, o ambiente é pesado e isso é notório! Nós sabemos que os poucos que ainda entram em sala, entram única e exclusivamente por nós. Eu sempre ouvi que professor era professor por amor e vinha aquela velha piada de que se trabalhassem por amor trabalhariam de graça. Pois bem, agora eles continuam trabalhando, mesmo sem salário e não vão apenas cumprir horário não! Eles entram em sala, ensinam e nunca são ríspidos conosco por estarem trabalhando \"de graça\", nunca se negam a tirar dúvidas.
Vemos cada um deles tentando nos preservar, nunca misturando as coisas, nunca faltando com a ética, nos poupando até onde der, mas nós somos bem grandinhos para saber que essa luta não é só de vocês, ela também é nossa! Essa luta se dá porque vocês querem nos ensinar com dignidade, mas mesmo que não falte vontade não podemos fazer muito. Nenhuma dessas palavras pagará suas contas, alimentará seus filhos, lhes proporcionará viagens ou lhes darão poder aquisitivo para comprarem coisas para nosso benefício. Tenham certeza de que se pudéssemos, arcaríamos com o salário de vocês, mas não podemos.
Vocês fazem mais do que merecemos, mas se tem algo que queremos pedir é que não desistam, pois nós reconhecemos tudo de uma maneira estranha, confessamos! 
Vocês são tudo o que precisamos para sermos melhores, vocês são os únicos que podem nos ajudar a mudar o mundo, o nosso mundo, a fazer um futuro melhor. Tenham certeza que nada disso será esquecido. Nós, alunos, amamos vocês e reconhecemos tudo isso! Não desistam, estamos com vocês\"",
      "created_time": "2016-02-24T01:00:59+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_945973868825236"
    },
    {
      "message": "Qualquer problema, sugestão, reclamação ou elogio vocês pode, entrar em contato com a SEEDUC por meio desde serviço!",
      "created_time": "2016-02-20T00:11:50+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_943556079067015"
    },
    {
      "message": "Podcast exalando amor em clima de Valentine's Day <3 <3
https://soundcloud.com/interbrusa/3-semana-de-fevereiro-2016?utm_source=soundcloud&utm_campaign=share&utm_medium=facebook",
      "created_time": "2016-02-16T00:11:45+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_941337615955528"
    },
    {
      "message": "Está chegando, segunda vamos gravar!! Contagem regressiva para o #Podcast2016",
      "created_time": "2016-02-12T17:32:43+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_939518906137399"
    },
    {
      "message": "#EuAmoOBrizolo e o Marcelo está nos nossos corações ❤",
      "created_time": "2016-02-03T19:12:43+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_934884803267476"
    },
    {
      "message": "#EuAmoOBrizolo e quero ouvir as tretas desse ano ",
      "created_time": "2016-02-03T19:10:47+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_934884213267535"
    },
    {
      "message": "#EuAmoOBrizolo e quero jogar bola ⚽",
      "created_time": "2016-02-03T19:09:30+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_934883703267586"
    },
    {
      "message": "Estamos oficialmente na ativa, amigos! E para começar o ano em grande estilo já vamos lançar um novo quadro: Amo o brizolo. Enquanto estamos de férias as tirinhas começarão com \"Não sinto falta do brizolo...\" e depois começarão com \"Amo o brizolo...\". Tem algum fato e quer colocar na tirinha? Mande sua sugestão para nossa página!",
      "story": "Inter BRUSA added 7 new photos.",
      "created_time": "2016-01-31T14:26:42+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_933226190100004"
    },
    {
      "message": "Já é terça-feira hein! #TerçasComAnaMariaBragaNoCiep117",
      "created_time": "2016-01-31T02:00:26+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_932973743458582"
    },
    {
      "message": "ATENÇÃO! TODAS as vagas para nossa escola foram preenchidas, você pode ir direto na escola para tentar uma vaga no dia 15/02, se alguém desistir. 
A equipe do Inter BRUSA sente muito por todos os que não conseguiram uma vaga.",
      "created_time": "2016-01-28T22:27:15+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_931786140244009"
    },
    {
      "message": "E aí, estão aproveitando as férias? A pedido da direção viemos informar que as aulas voltam dia 02 de Fevereiro e que já começam com o horário NORMAL (07 h  às 16 h 50 min). Esperamos encontrar todos vocês no colégio ❤",
      "created_time": "2016-01-27T18:16:35+0000",
      "id": "671053616317264_931194423636514"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/671053616317264/feed?format=json&since=1457038820&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAF9ecziqGZB8xSqVTizFl43sAf6djs3hZBOkbNOyHQhGHqOVuKVc6onEvZBX2ex9RrZBGuCpFaoc8UKGC8qu21qczyvQbtisL5VC8TAmPv7ZAiEoPgTnZBWSP51Dw3VvuD2OktKuvUrFHNZB8wkeA73VnEDl7f3XK5OudBG94YRne7v36Y2dLSfqVsmKb1NJw2zVCAauGEk&limit=25&__paging_token=enc_AdBXLaYB2vvx1iZAtKcIOyaFEWA1UqjMiHq9NdZBCW2ncJFHjqeDnsKWpYyeGBtHY4CtO7QPRAd3RQjRb5UhZCpB7o1nT5mHUIv9UbIUSMyQDzB6wZDZD&__previous=1",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/671053616317264/feed?format=json&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAF9ecziqGZB8xSqVTizFl43sAf6djs3hZBOkbNOyHQhGHqOVuKVc6onEvZBX2ex9RrZBGuCpFaoc8UKGC8qu21qczyvQbtisL5VC8TAmPv7ZAiEoPgTnZBWSP51Dw3VvuD2OktKuvUrFHNZB8wkeA73VnEDl7f3XK5OudBG94YRne7v36Y2dLSfqVsmKb1NJw2zVCAauGEk&limit=25&until=1453918595&__paging_token=enc_AdDFXFfqzctp4YGgbS3wLjAhS8gETcvtsEOaBSwZAtOlpFK4W0WrAXPMdr50IFNZCIz2hg8U4t81c5HCPShGXUhZA5SgeyeGtq2G57vAtEC6wrJPQZDZD"
  }
}
```

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: If you have valid JSON string then you can use below PHP function to convert JSON string to PHP array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (assuming you JSON is valid):

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($jsonArray['data'] as $data) {
   $post[] = isset($data['story']) ? $data['story'] : $data['message'];
}
```

OUTPUT

```
var_dump($post);

array(25) {
  [0] =>
  string(45) "Inter BRUSA shared Jornalistas Livress photo."
  [1] =>
  string(116) "Veja como foi a jornada do Inter BRUSA no ato de ontem!     Desde Nova Iguaçu até a Cinelândia!
#westandwitheducation"
  [2] =>
  string(49) "Inter BRUSA shared Integral da depressãos photo."
  [3] =>
  string(184) ""O que eles roubaram foi bem mais do que dinheiro
    Roubaram nosso orgulho de ser brasileiro
    Mas isso ainda conservo
    Podem acabar com a nossa verba
    Mas não podem acabar com nosso verbo""
```